# Rpart R Decision Tree Score

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, decision-tree, rpart

In Python using SkLearn, you could use the following to create and receive a score on a Decision Tree:

```
tr = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=rseed, min_samples_split=2, ccp_alpha=0.005)
model_tree = tr.fit(train_features, train_outputs)

print(f'Model Train Accuracy: {model_tree.score(train_features, train_outputs)}')
print(f'Model Test Accuracy: {model_tree.score(test_features, test_outputs)}')
```

The above produces

```
Model Train Accuracy: 0.5942
Model Test Accuracy: 0.4933
```

How can I get similar scores in R (on the Training and testing data) using R's Rpart?

Comment: Take a look at [Calculating prediction accuracy of a tree using rpart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40080794/4752675)

Answer (score 1):

In short:

1. Calculate the error rate as shown below
2. Make sure to use the same parameters and control parameters in python and R (see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rpart/versions/4.1-15/topics/rpart.control)

```r
model_tree <- rpart(Response ~ Predictor1 + PredictorX,
                    data = train, method = "class",
                    control = list(cp = 0.005, minsplit = 2, ...))

pred_train <- predict(model_tree, type = "class")
pred_test <- predict(model_tree, newdata = test, type = "class")

# error rate / accuracy (train set)
mean(pred_train != train$Response)

# error rate / accuracy (test set)
mean(pred_test != test$Response)
```